# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\left(\frac{3i}{n}\right)^2-\left(\frac{3i}{n}\right)\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, gre-exam

How to evaluate the following?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\left(\frac{3i}{n}\right)^2-\left(\frac{3i}{n}\right)\right)$$

I simply expanded but I did not find the answer. I think there might be some trick or clever observation, but now I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Think in terms of a Riemann sum:  what definite integral might this correspond to?

Comment: Would someone please explain why you voted to close this question? I thought it's a valid math question :(

Comment: @RecklessReckoner I don't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum), so we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{3}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\left(\frac{3k}{n}\right)^{2}-\frac{3k}{n}\right)=3\int_{0}^{1}(9x^{2}-3x)\,dx=\color{red}{\frac{9}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6},$$
we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\left(\frac{3i}{n}\right)^2-\left(\frac{3i}{n}\right)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3}{n}(\frac{9}{n^2}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{3}{n}\frac{n(n+1)}{2})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3}{n}\frac{3}{2n}(n+1)^2=\frac{9}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

prove that your term  has the form $$\frac{3}{n}\cdot \frac{3(n+1)^2}{2n}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\,{3 \over n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}
\bracks{\pars{3i \over n}^{2} - \pars{3i \over n}}} =
27\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over n^{3}}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}i^{2}} -
9\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over n^{2}}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}i}
\end{align}

---

However, with $\ds{k = 1,2}$ and *Stolz-Cesàro Theorem*:
\begin{align}
\fbox{$\ds{\ \lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n^{\color{#f00}{k} + 1}}
\sum_{n = 1}^{n}i^{\color{#f00}{k}}\ }$}
& =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\pars{n + 1}^{k} \over \pars{n + 1}^{k + 1} - n^{k + 1}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum_{\ell = 0}^{k - 1}{k \choose \ell}n^{\ell}\ +\ n^{k} \over
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{k - 1}{k + 1 \choose \ell}n^{\ell}\ +\ \pars{k + 1}n^{k}}
\\[4mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum_{\ell = 0}^{k - 1}{k \choose \ell}n^{\ell - k}\ +\ 1 \over
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{k - 1}{k + 1 \choose \ell}n^{\ell - k}\ +\ \pars{k + 1}} =
\fbox{$\ds{\ {1 \over \color{#f00}{k} + 1}\ }$}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{\left.\quad\lim_{n \to \infty}\,\,n^{\ell - k}
> \,\,\right\vert_{\ \ell\ <\ k}\,\,\, =\, \color{#f00}{0}}$.

---

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\,{3 \over n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}
\bracks{\pars{3i \over n}^{2} - \pars{3i \over n}}} =
27\,{1 \over \color{#f00}{2} + 1} - 9\,{1 \over \color{#f00}{1} + 1} =
\color{#f00}{9 \over 2}
\end{align}